# A multiple choice question on the system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following system of linear equations.
$x + y + z + w = b_1$;
$x - y + 2z + 3w = b_2$;
$x - 3y + 3z + 5w = b_3$;
$x + 3y - w = b_4$.
For which of the following choices of $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$, $b_4$ does the above system have a
solution?

$(A)$ $b_1$ $= 1$; $b_2$ $= 0$; $b_3$ $= -1$; $b_4$ $= 2$

$(B)$ $b_1$ $= 2$; $b_2$ $= 3$; $b_3$ $= 5$; $b_4$ $= -1$

$(C)$$b_1$ $= 2$; $b_2$ $= 2$; $b_3$ $= 3$; $b_4$ $= 0$

$(D)$ $b_1$ $= 2$; $b_2$ $= -1$; $b_3$ $= -3$; $b_4$ $= 3$.

I know that in the system of equation $Ax=b$
 if rank$(A)$$\geq$ rank$(A|b)$ then the linear equations have a solution.But here I think it is very lengthy.Is their any other method for solve this problem? somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the first and second equation, then add the third and fourth equations you have the following pair of equations:-
$$2x+3z+4w=b_1+b_2$$
$$2x+3z+4w=b_3+b_4$$

For the above equations to have a solution, $b_1+b_2$ must equal $b_3+b_4$, as the LHS are the same. Can you identify which of the choices satisfy this condition?

Comment: Yes option $(A)$.Thank you.

Comment: That is correct, and you are welcome.